# CSS image overlay delay display:none to display:block

Tags: html, css

**I have an image with a button on it**. The button will only be **visible**, if I **hover** over the image.

I change it from `display:none` to `display:block` and it appears instantly.

I would like to delay the appearance of this button by 1 sec or make it appear linear, so it's a smooth transition. I saw the CSS3 `transition` property and applied this, by using `opacity`, too `(0.0 to 1.0)`.

It seems not to be working. What am I missing? I don't think the `-webkit` specific properties are the reason.

**Check out my fiddle.js example:**

> [Fiddle.js: Image hover over overlay transition example](http://jsfiddle.net/sNXc3/4)

Thank you!

Comment: i see no try of transition, opacity, nor even a button in your fiddle ?

Comment: You fiddle is missing some code ....

Comment: I updated it, it didnt save my changes before :) sorry

Comment: Also, you are going to need to include the relevant code in your question as well (not just JSFiddle) so that it can help others years from now.

Comment: Here is OP jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sNXc3/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sNXc3/4/

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNXc3/5/ You shouldn't set display property to none

Comment: Exactly what I need Wolff. I was unsure if `opacity`is handled like `visibility` property and not `display`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNXc3/6/)

I have use `all` instead of `opacity`, but either way you can change that too.

```
.image_controls{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:5px;
    opacity:0.0;


}

.image_wrapper:hover .image_controls {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    display: block;
    opacity:.9;

}
```

Comment: thanks @rockStar also working. I upvoted, but wolff did answer first.

Comment: its cool bro, as long as you got your answer.

Comment: @zer02 you could still consider to accept this answer ;)

Comment: his fiddle was just fine if display:none was removed. transition works only on value that can be incremented (or oppposite) , display is a state !

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()`. As you tagged javascript and jquery, I guess using JS would not be a concern for you, right?

Comment: I unchecked javascript/jquery now. I would need the CSS(3) option.